# Android Widget - Two Lines?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to make a simple widget and I need to make it in two lines. Apparently I can't use a table for that, so I'm a bit stuck on how to do it.

This is my code

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</FrameLayout>
```

And this is what I'm trying to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Jc7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use a `LinearLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
[...]
>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/myFirstRow"
[...]
>
<myUiElements />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mySecondRow"
[...]
>
<myUiElements />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `Relativelayout` to achieve this as from your image I can see that you want to ovelay things on some other layout and in this case you would require a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your `<FrameLayout>` as containers for dynamically added Fragments or something else?

**If yes** then use a `<RelativeLayout>` to wrap the two `<FrameLayout>` and use `android:layout_below=""` to align one below the other.

**Otherwise** just use [Ahmad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333975/ahmad) example.